# Exception :"main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.readLines(java.io.InputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset)'

Tags: java, ioutils

I am getting below error.
I have tried with common.io.2.11.0/2.10.0/2.9/2.8/2.7..
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.readLines(java.io.InputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset)'
at com.appiancorp.ps.automatedtest.common.PropertiesUtilities.loadProperties(PropertiesUtilities.java:28)
at com.appiancorp.ps.automatedtest.fixture.BaseFixture.(BaseFixture.java:66)
at com.appiancorp.ps.automatedtest.fixture.TempoFixture.(TempoFixture.java:104)
at com.appiancorp.ps.automatedtest.fixture.SitesFixture.(SitesFixture.java:11)
at com.appiancorp.example.HelloAppian.main(HelloAppian.java:22)
anybody knows this error , pls help.

Pls find the code below:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import com.appiancorp.ps.automatedtest.fixture.SitesFixture;
public class HelloAppian {
  protected static String TEST_BROWSER = "CHROME";
  protected static String TEST_SITE_VERSION = "22.1";
  protected static String TEST_SITE_URL = "/";
  protected static String TEST_SITE_LOCALE = "en_US";
  protected static String TEST_USERNAME = ""; //Make sure this username has an entry in users.properties
  protected static Integer TEST_TIMEOUT = 60;

 private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(HelloAppian.class);
  public static SitesFixture fixture;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   LOG.debug("Setting up Tempo Fixture");

   fixture = new SitesFixture();

   fixture.setTakeErrorScreenshotsTo(true);
   fixture.setupWithBrowser(TEST_BROWSER);
   fixture.setAppianUrlTo(TEST_SITE_URL);
   fixture.setTimeoutSecondsTo(TEST_TIMEOUT);
   fixture.setAppianVersionTo(TEST_SITE_VERSION);
   fixture.setAppianLocaleTo(TEST_SITE_LOCALE);
   fixture.loginWithUsername(TEST_USERNAME);
   fixture.clickOnMenu("Actions");
   fixture.clickOnAction("Create a Case");
   fixture.verifyButtonIsPresent("Submit");
   fixture.tearDown();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code and minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: According to the [`IOUtils.readLines()` documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#readLines-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-) the method exists since release 2.3. I'm not sure what version appian includes or how you can include your specific version with appian.

Comment: You don't need it. Use `java.io.BufferedReader.lines()`.

Comment: @ThomasKläger , this sample program uses appian-selenium-api-22.1.1.jar.